# Replace multiple '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' with HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

Working on a strange one today - A client will be pasting in a load of text to an HTML editor which adds many non breaking spaces. I need to style this when output to the browser.

I am trying to make the following string

```
<ul class="columns">
    <li><u>Running costs</u></li>
    <li>Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 50.4 mpg</li>
    <li>Extra Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 72.4 mpg</li>
</ul>
```

Change to this:

```
<ul class="columns">
    <li><u>Running costs</u></li>
    <li>Urban mpg<span class="right">50.4 mpg</span></li>
    <li>Extra Urban mpg<span class="right">72.4 mpg</span></li>
</ul>
```

Using preg replace or an HTML parser. I have tried both. My PHP preg_replace is this:

```
preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)/", "<span>", $input_lines);
```

Which replaces all &nspb;'s with . I only want the one span to be added and I need it to close at the end too. I have been experminting with Simple HTML Dom but not sure what functions to use to best achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: echo preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+([^<]+)</', '<span class="right">\2</span>', $input_lines);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
(?:&nbsp;)+([^<]*)
```

Replace with

```
<span class="right">\1</span>
```

It matches all repeating `&nbsp;`, and then grabs everything up to `<` of the closing tag. Replacing it with the above string inserts the capture with the surrounding `span`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sM7rS8/3).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css selector, you'd need the escaped unicode value.

```
span.right::before {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to output the spaces; I am trying to replace them with a span using PHP

Comment: My apologies, misread the question. I'd recommend the answer provided by @ClasG.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<?php
$text = '<ul class="columns">
    <li><u>Running costs</u></li>
    <li>Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 50.4 mpg</li>
    <li>Extra Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 72.4 mpg</li>
</ul>';

$new_text = preg_replace("/(?:&nbsp;)+([^<]*)/", " <span class=\"right\">\${1}</span>", $text);
echo $new_text;
```

Result: https://eval.in/600085

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$text = "<ul class='columns'>
<li><u>Running costs</u></li>
<li>Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 50.4 mpg</li>
<li>Extra Urban mpg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 72.4 mpg</li>
</ul>";    
echo $text;
$pattern = '/(&nbsp;)+([\w\.\s]+)(<\/li>)/'; 
$text = preg_replace($pattern,'<span class="name">$2</span>', $text);

echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```